# CoffeeScript calling a method of returned object ( chaining )

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, chaining

Say I've got the code:

```
cat = {
    feed: (food) ->
        alert "cat ate #{food}"
}

pets = {
    "maximus": cat
}

getPet = (name) ->
    pets[name]
```

How can I invoke the "feed" method of returned by "getPet" cat object? This is not a valid code:

```
getPet "maximus" feed "Fish"
```

In plain javascript it would look like this:

```
getPet("maximus").feed("Fish");
```

Comment: I'll leave a comment since I really don't know much about CS, but using their online CS evaluator, I got it to work with `(getPet "maximus").feed "Fish"`. Someone who's more familiar may have a better way.

Comment: Alright. Other methods I see around SO seem to simply reintroduce the `()`. `getPet("maximus").feed "Fish"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do chaining without the parentheses on the left-most parts of the chain.

```
getPet('maximus').feed 'fish'
```

Comment: It's a pity. I've got quite long sequences. But, parentheses are ok anyway! Thanks.

Comment: One more reason why dropping the parenthesis in CS is not a good thing. I really wish this "feature" was not in CS. Now, that it is, our team has decided to leave them off the predicate for if-statements but leave them in just about everywhere else. I think that it hurts readability to leave them off and saves nothing but a few keystrokes.

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb for me is to use parenthesis when you're assigning whatever the method returns, so a = runMethod(x), but I avoid including them otherwise. I only use them in a conditional if there's more than one test.

Comment: Ultimately though, wether you use parenthesis or not is a preference that is up to you and your team to decide. Come up with a convention and make sure every follows that style. ...I know, easier said than done :)